# Python and Thread: instance has no __call__ method

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a problem extending Thread class in Python. This is my simple code:

```
import threading

class position:

    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id = id

class foo(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        self.start = position(0)
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = foo()
    f.start()
```

The shown error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 19, in <module>
    f.start()
AttributeError: position instance has no __call__ method
```

Where is the error? i have spended 3 hours searching for a solution, but i can't find one.
I have extended Thread class many time during my work, but this time it won't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've overwritten the `start` method with your `position` instance. Name your `position` property differently.

E.g.

```
import threading

class position:

    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id = id

class foo(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        self.start_position = position(0)   # self.start is now unharmed
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = foo()
    f.start()
```

Comment: Can you 'redo' the source code? I don't understand what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

You have hidden the `Thread.start` method with your `start` field in the constructor.

Either rename the field (to startedAt, for instance), or if you insist on leaving it called `start`, use `foo.start(f)`